# Java Hibernate check if a value exists

Tags: java, hibernate, unique

Mysql table Employee uses employeeID as PK. It also has a field called EmployeeNumber. EmployeeNumber is either null or unique. (Some special employees don't have an employee#). When inserting an employee entry we need check if employee# is already if employee# is not null.

Don't know how to do it using Hibernate.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code. Either query the table before the insert to see if the employee # already exists, or create a unique index on the employee # and insert the row. If the unique index fails your transaction, you can inspect the exception to confirm that is why it failed and branch your logic from there.

Comment: If you have an unique constraint for a nullable column, you won't be able to have more than one row with NULL value. At least on some DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a mechanism to generate the primary keys for the Employee entity?
calling session.save() in Hibernate will fail if the employee Id already exists.